# How can I include content of a component in Fabricator Assemble *without* a corresponding attribute, or at block level?

Tags: fabricator, fabricator-assemble

In [Fabricator Assemble](https://github.com/fbrctr/fabricator-assemble), I could have a component **button.html**:

```html
<a class="button">{{text}}</a>
```

I can use this with the syntax `{{>button text='Home'}}`. Notably, I have to **specify a name for the "text" attribute**.

I'm looking to see how I can handle *not* needing to do that in Assemble. [The Literals section of the docs for Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) (whiich Fabricator Assemble is built on) highlights an alternative syntax with which I could include a button:

```html
{{>button 'Home'}}
```

In this example, "Home" is **a value without any name for it at all.** Handlebars also indicates the following is possible as a [basic block](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html):

```html
{{#button}}
  <b>Some button content</b>
{{/button}}
```

Likewise, that content has no name.

I'd like to be able to do this same thing in Fabricator Assemble, but it doesn't seem to have a way for me to include this nameless content. In templates there's `{% body %}` but that doesn't work here.

In Handlebars, which Fabricator Assemble is based on, all examples for how to recreate this involve JavaScript, which doesn't translate well to Assemble.

What can I do to use `{{>button 'Some text'}}` or `{{#button}}...{{/button}}` syntax in Fabricator Assemble? Is this behaviour even available?

Answer (score 1):

In the current version, the easiest way to achieve this is with a custom helper.

Add the following to the `helpers` option in your `gulpfile.js`:

```
default: (value, defaultValue) => {
  return value || defaultValue;
},
```

Then inside a handlebars template:

```
<div>
  {{default varName 'default value'}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for checking this out, Luke. I caused a miscommunication here through some poor choice of words -- it's not that I want to have default values with the attributes I specify, but I want to use an attribute-less property: instead of `{{>button text='Some text'}}`, I want to use `{{>button 'Some text'}}` or `{{#button}}<b>Some text</b>{{/button}}`. Handlebars supports that, and Fab Assemble is built on Handlebars so I presume there's a way, but I'm not sure what the reference is for that attribute-less value: `{{content}}`, `{{body}}` etc don't work.

Comment: That said this is kind of awesome and I didn't think about having this kind of behaviour, and it would be really useful inside the component library. [edits into project]